# WhatsApp location_request_message is not Working! OAuthException - whatsapp interactive messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location, whatsapp, interactive

I am trying to send the "location_request_message" through postman and it's responses with an error

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Param interactive['type'] must be one of {ADDRESS_MESSAGE, BUTTON, CATALOG_MESSAGE, GALAXY_MESSAGE, LIST, MENU_OPTIONS, MESSAGE_WITH_LINK, MESSAGE_WITH_LINK_STATUS, ORDER_DETAILS, ORDER_STATUS, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_LIST} - got \"location_request_message\".",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AgvvDCuplk_cuF-hR4oQCTD"
    }
}
```

Artifacts to reproduce:-

Here is the payload(JSON) -->

```json
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "<phone_number>",
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive":{
            "type": "location_request_message",
            "body": {
              "type": "text",
              "text": "Please provide your location"
            },
            "action": {
              "name": "send_location" 
            }         
 }
}
```

URL:- https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<phone_number_id>/messages

and we also need to send the access token in the header.

I have tried with node.js also with the postman. Its working for other Interactive Messages but not working for Location Request!

Comment: Did you get a work around ?